# ¿Como arreglo este Deque para solucionar el problema que me dan?

Tags: java, condiciones, bucles, estructuras-de-datos, pilas

Hola tengo un problema con el Deque y es que nose como arreglarlo para solucinar con lo que me piden, estoy estancado en como resolver el problema, nose me ocurre nada mas ayuda, intente hacer esto:

Este es el problema:

[image]

Estoy estancado es en la aplicacion del Deque y no se que hacer

Este es mi codigo:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Josefo {
    
    static BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
        int tamanaio = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
        
        for (int i = 0; i < tamanaio; i++) {
            
            String texto = br.readLine();
            String[] dato = texto.split(" ");
            int numero1 = Integer.parseInt(dato[0]);
            int numero2 = Integer.parseInt(dato[1]);
            proceso(numero1, numero2);
        }
    }
    
     private static void proceso(int numero1 , int numero2) {

      Deque<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();

        for(int i=1; i<=numero1;i++){
          queue.add(i);
        }
            
        for (int i = 1; i < numero1; i++) {
            
            queue.remove();
            queue.add(queue.poll());  //mueve el primero a la cola

          //aqui que debo hacer AYUDA, esto esta mal pero no se me ocurre nada
        }
        
        
        System.out.println(queue.getFirst());
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vamos por partes:

En primer lugar, para capturar lo que quieras introducir por teclado no hace falta que obtengas el tamaño y lo recorras con un `for` ya que sabes que la entrada será del tipo *numero1 numero2*. También he modificado el nombre de las variables para que se entienda mejor:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String entrada = scanner.nextLine();
    String[] strings = entrada.split(" ");
    int tamanio = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);
    int posicion = Integer.parseInt(strings[1]);

    proceso(tamanio, posicion);
}
```

La solución que te doy para el método `proceso` está implementada usando la estructura `Deque` para modificar lo menos posible tu código, aunque existen estructuras de datos más eficientes.

```
private static void proceso(int tamanio, int posicion) {

    Deque<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int i = 1; i <= tamanio; i++)
        queue.add(i);

    while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= posicion; i++) {
            int posEliminada = queue.remove();

            if (i != posicion)
                queue.add(posEliminada);
        }
        if (queue.size() == 1)
            System.out.println(queue.getFirst());
    }
}
```

Espero que te sirva `:)`

Comment: Muchisimas gracias por tu ayuda :D

Answer (score 0):

private static void proceso(int tamanio, int posicion) {

```
Deque<Integer> queue = new LinkedList<>();

for (int i = 1; i <= tamanio; i++)
    queue.add(i);

while (!queue.isEmpty()) {
    for (int i = 1; i <= posicion; i++) {
        int posEliminada = queue.remove();

        if (i != posicion)
            queue.add(posEliminada);
    }
    if (queue.size() == 1)
        System.out.println(queue.getFirst());
}
```

}

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).